# What's the technical definition for "routine"?

Tags: definition, routines

I'm studying lisp language (to do lisp routines) and in a general context i know what's a routine, but in a technical context i can talk about it, because i'm starting to learn routines now. So, what's the real definition of routine? 
(i've already "googled" this but didn't find anything)

Answer (score 49, accepted):

The term *routine* derives from [*subroutine*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Subroutine), which is a more common term in languages like BASIC where one actually creates SUBroutines. (BASIC actually had a difference between a SUBroutine and a FUNCTION, but nevertheless...)

From the Wikipedia entry:

> > In computer science, a subroutine (*also called procedure, function, routine, method, or subprogram*) is **a portion of code within a larger program that performs a specific task and is *relatively* independent of the remaining code.**
> >
> > As the name "subprogram" suggests, a subroutine behaves in much the same way as a computer program that is used as one step in a larger program or another subprogram. A subroutine is often coded so that it can be started ("called") several times and/or from several places during a single execution of the program, including from other subroutines, and then branch back (return) to the next instruction after the "call" once the subroutine's task is done.

Different languages/environments/eras have different ecosystems and thus different terms to describe the same general concept. I generally only use the term *function* (or *method* in an "OOP" environment) these days.

Happy coding.

---

For fun I have Community Wiki'ed. The list below is hopefully to cover which term(s) is (are) "correct" (widely accepted) to use in a given language to mean *routine*. Informally *routine* is used in context of all the languages below so it should be omitted unless it is the defacto term used. Feel free to add, correct, and annotate as appropriate.

- C - [function](http://www.imada.sdu.dk/~svalle/courses/dm14-2005/mirror/c/section3_9.html)
- Java - [method](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/methods.html). While function is also often used, the term function *does not appear* in the [Java Language Specification](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/jls/).
- C# - [method and function](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms228593.aspx). In the specification, functions refer to function-objects and anonymous functions. They are not the same as methods, which are members of types (classes or structures). Also consider delegates.
- JavaScript - [function or method](http://sharkysoft.com/tutorials/jsa/content/039.html). Methods are functions accessed via a property of an object.
- Haskell - [function](http://www.haskell.org/haskellwiki/Function). This is *the* accepted terminology.
- Scala - [function or method](http://jim-mcbeath.blogspot.com/2009/05/scala-functions-vs-methods.html). Method if `def` member of type, functions are first-class values.
- BASIC - [function or subroutine](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/BASIC_Programming/Subroutines_and_Functions). Subroutines do not return values. Supports call-by-reference.
- FORTRAN - [function or subroutine](http://www-classes.usc.edu/engr/ce/108/text/fbk05.htm). Subroutines do not return values. Supports call-by-reference.
- LISP - [function](http://www.svbug.com/documentation/lisp/node16.html). DEFUN -> DEfineFUNction, all forms are valid expressions. Also consider [macros](http://www.apl.jhu.edu/~hall/Lisp-Notes/Macros.html), which are not themselves functions but are arguably routines.
- VHDL - [subprograms: functions and procedures](http://www.cs.umbc.edu/portal/help/VHDL/design.html#subpr). Procedures have no return value.
- SmallTalk - [method](http://www.jmcsweeney.co.uk/computing/m206/methods.php)
- Python - [method](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Python_%28programming_language%29#Methods)
- Ruby - [method](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Ruby_Programming/Syntax/Method_Calls) (often interchanged with function? lambdas/Procs may be considered different?)
- Perl - [function and subroutine](http://perlmaven.com/subroutines-and-functions-in-perl). There is only one form to declare a function/SUBroutine so there is no distinction w.r.t. return values. Using method (for object-bound functions) seems less prevalent than in other languages.
- Pascal - [procedures and functions](http://www.freepascal.org/docs-html/ref/refch14.html#x158-16800014)
- Ada - [procedures and functions](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Ada_Programming/Subprograms)

Answer (score 2):

You can't find a technical definition because there isn't a technical definition specific to lisp. A 'routine', outside of vaudeville, is just another name for a function. While it's been many years since I programmed in Lisp full-time, no one ever used that term in any formal way, or even used it commonly. We talked about 'functions', 'macros', and 'forms.' If someone said, 'oh, there's a routine to calculate how many apples in a pie' it was perfectly informal.